# How To Run A Process Command on Mac?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to practice this Process class but it's been a flop since I could not figure out how to write the filenames and the paths correctly.

This is what I'm trying out but everytime I get the same error: ***Unhandled exception. System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (2): No such file or directory***

```
Process.Start("/Applications/Utilities/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit");
```

I tried different paths which were not much different from this one, but as I said idk what to do about this.

Do you know what's the accurate way of doing that?

Comment: File names and directories use backslash as the delimiter. You are using forward slash. Also, you need to include the full file name, including its extension (which might be hidden in Windows Explorer).

Comment: @JohnWu Presumably if they are running on a Mac paths will not use backslashes and they do not have Windows Explorer

Comment: On my linux machine, `Process.Start("/path/to/executable")` works, so I don't think this is an issue of path formatting. Is `TextEdit` itself the executable?

Comment: @bisen2 Hey, I figured this out. This is all about the path issue. The error I got was totally correct. There is no such path and the correct way of doing it is /System/Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/Textedit at least on Catalina.

Answer (score 1):

please use this code :

```
using (Process myProcess = new Process())
{
    myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
    myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    myProcess.Start();
}
```